# amazon ec2 elastic ip redirecting not wroking

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I've registered domain with bigrock.in

1. Created ec2 instance in aws
2. created elastic ip
3. registered with route53 and gave my domain name
4. changed the name servers in bigrock with the provided names in bigrock
5. ssh to the ec2 instance with elastic ip
6. ran node.js app with forever 
   with the following environemnt variables

   `export ROOT_URL="www.domain.com"`

at the time of route53 process, I created A record with www sub-domain to elasticIp

But, I'm not seeing anything at `domain.com` or at elasticIp `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`

Did I miss any steps, Is there anything wrong I did or do I need to do anything to make this works

**EDIT**

I haven't added any A or CNAME records to bigrock just changed the name server to the servers provided by ROuter53

**Edit 2**

that is my security group outbound details, My app is running on port 80.
Are those settings correct?
[image]

**EDIT 3**
My INbound rules
[image]

Comment: Did you Open PORT 80 [ or the port the node app is running ] to 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: Check if you have correctly opened port 80 (or 443 in case of HTTPS) in the Security group assigned to your ec2 Instance.
The steps you have mentioned are correct.

Comment: @Naveen Ive added the image of my security settings,how to enable the port?

Comment: @DeepakNaik, Ive added the image of my security settings,how to enable the port?

Comment: Inbound rules are more likely to be relevant (outbound defaults to everything allowed)

Comment: @FrederickCheung, for Inbound there is only one record for ssh with port 22 open

Comment: @FrederickCheung I've added the image for inbound rules

Answer (score 0):

You've got a rule to allow all traffic from anywhere on the INBOUND security groups so its not that (make sure you fix this later when you get it working - as it is, its a bit of a security hole).

Next thing I would normally say is its a dns problem, but as you say you've tried going to the eip as well as the domain name its not that either.

Next likely candidates are:

- The server isnt listening - it may be that it hasnt started properly try checking the logs,
- The machine's firewall is blocking connections. (try turning it off - keep this at VERY short time length though - its a huge risk in combination with your security group settings)
- Or your server is not listening on port 80, e.g. it might be listening on 8080 or 443. Check the server config - by default browsers assume port 80 for http, if its not listening on that you will have to specify the port in the address bar as well e.g. http://example.com:8080